# Using custom fonts in React App not working across all browsers

Tags: css, reactjs, browser, fonts

So I am using a few custom .woff fonts by loading them in using @font-face and storing them within my src folder. When running the app locally my fonts all work, but after deploying the app to the live domain Chrome and Firefox do not load the fonts for desktop. They do however load on Safari (Desktop and Mobile), Chrome(Mobile), Firefox(Mobile). I am wondering why these fonts will not load on desktop versions of Chrome and Firefox. Do these browsers not read .woff fonts?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because I was hosting it on Github pages and using a custom domain created a CORS issue. I fixed this by moving my font files into the public folder and creating a CSS file in the public folder as well to load in the fonts.